# How to use one external hard drive to back up Windows and Linux as well as macOS with Time Machine?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, partitioning, backup

I have an external hard disk drive I use for all of my backups.

- I created an NTFS partition that I backed up Windows 10 to.
- Then I created an ext4 partition and backed up Linux Mint to that.
- Now, I created another 300gb of unallocated space that I'm trying to back up my MacBook to using Time Machine.

The Mac disk utility app only shows the NTFS partition and doesn't show the free space so I could create a new partition.

Can I create an APFS partition from Windows/Linux and then set Time Machine to use that space for its backup? Or is this just not possible to back up all 3 operations systems on a single external drive?

It seems like Mac wants its own hard disk drive with no other partitions to use Time Machine.

Comment: What OS? Big Sur needs APFS, anything earlier must have HFS+ Your disk will need to be GUID not MBR. idk how this will affect the WIn & nix backups.

Comment: @Tetsujin it is Big Sur

Comment: It is possible to use Time Machine on any filesystem as long as you create a sparse disk image on your Mac, copy it to the other drive and share the drive from that computer. There are lots of how-to's around and just an internet search away.

Answer (score 0):

### Time Machine won’t work on a partition alone; it needs to take over the  whole disk.

> “It seems like Mac wants its own hard disk drive with no other partitions to use Time Machine.”

Yup. [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250) formats the disk it uses for backups in its own way. So there is no way to designate a specific partition on a drive to just be Time Machine; it’s all or nothing.

That said, you could use a macOS tool like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) to backup to a specific partition. The software is basically Rysnc on steroids with some native macOS snapshot support as well. More details can be [found here](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/how-set-up-your-first-backup); very solid software with excellent support and documentation.

Comment: TM will work to an APFS **container** smaller than the entire drive, it will insist on using all of that as one partition. The end result is you can use part of a disk, same as with HFS+

Comment: @Tetsujin . i have really been struggling with getting TM to work on an external drive that i created 2 partitions on (1 dedicated to TM ). whats strange is macos usually refuses to even mount that partition (meaning... i havent even tried running TM app yet.. just plugged in the usb drive).     i can sometimes get it to mount by inserting the usb cable very slowly into the dongle.   

can i avoid all this mess if i create a container instead of a partition on an external HD?